# Set a time limit for a java Boggle game

Tags: java, timer, limit, boggle

I have written code that solves a boggle board and now I want to convert it into my own game. I have everything I need except I cannot figure out how to set a time limit so the person can only enter words in for a 2 minutes. This is what I have so far, but it doesn't do what i want it to do, which is to stop after 2 mins.

```
            long startTime = System.nanoTime();
            long endTime1=0;
            long maxDurationInMilliseconds = 2 * 60 * 1000;
            while (2 * 60 * 1000> endTime1-startTime) {
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
                System.out.print("Guess a word on the board! ");
                if(test.CheckGame(scan.next())==true){
                    System.out.print("Good job! ");
                }
                else    
                    System.out.print("Guess again! ");
                endTime1 = System.nanoTime();
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing milliseconds with nanoseconds. That seems to be the problem here.

You should probably use [`System.currentTimeMillis`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) to calculate both `startTime` and `endTime1`.

Or if you need nanosecond resolution (though *not* guaranteed with [`System.nanoTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29)) you should represent *max duration* in nanoseconds.

Comment: thanks that actually works! however now my problem is is that it only is able to check the time after it goes through the loop so is there anyway to have a running timer? and is there any way to have the timer print out the clock?